# What is the fastest way to fill a ndarray by another ndarray using a lookup table

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, lookup-tables

I have 3 ndarrays:

- lookup_table[4,]
- color_image[height,width,3]
- gray_image[height,width]

"lookup_table" contains values for "red, green, blue" and "gray" value for each RGB
is there a high performance way to fill "gray_image" with corresponding "gray" value of "color_image" other than using nested for loops?

**In other words:**
I have these two arrays (lookup_table and rgb_image):

```
lookup_table = 
[ [ 19  92 192  25]
 [ 16  99 186  30]
 [ 14 106 179  35]
 [ 15 113 171  40]
 [ 19 121 164  45]
 [ 23 127 155  50]
 [ 31 134 146  55] ... ]   # [Red  Green  Blue  Gray_Equivalent]

rgb_image = 
[ [ 0  0  19  92 192]
  [ 0  1  19  92 192]
  [ 0  2  19  92 192]
  [ 0  3  23 127 155] ... ]    # [ X  Y  Red  Green  Blue]
```

I want to join them on [Red  Green  Blue] values and make a new array like this:

```
gray_image = 
[ [ 0  0  25]
  [ 0  1  25]
  [ 0  2  25]
  [ 0  3  50] ... ]     # [ X  Y  Gray_Equivalent]
```

Something like the output of this SQL query BUT in python:

```
SELECT  
    rgb_image.X, 
    rgb_image.Y, 
    lookup_table.Gray_Equivalent  
FROM rgb_image LEFT JOIN lookup_table ON
     rgb_image.Red = lookup_table.Red 
     rgb_image.Green= lookup_table.Green
     rgb_image.Blue= lookup_table.Blue
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how your arrays look like and what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you want `np.take()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65477131/2836621 or `cv2.LUT()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/61914386/2836621